# how to use decltype(*this) in clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Here is my code.

If i don't comment out the `// typedef auto getFoo1() -> decltype(*this);`，the program works on gcc，but it compiles failed on clang (https://godbolt.org/z/jzs3f6oM7).

```cpp
class Foo {
public:

    // not work on clang but work on gcc
    // typedef auto getFoo1() -> decltype(*this);

    auto getFoo2() -> decltype(*this);

};



int main() {
    Foo f;


    return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x86-64 clang 14.0.0 - 1232ms
Output of x86-64 clang 14.0.0 (Compiler #1)
<source>:6:41: error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function
    typedef auto getFoo1() -> decltype(*this);
```

And I want to know, what is the difference between the `getFoo1()` and the `getFoo2()`? And if `getFoo1()` and `getFoo2()` exists in memory or other place when running?

Comment: better godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/1fr7Kra46

Comment: offtopic: what is rationale to have this: `typedef auto getFoo1() -> decltype(*this);`? Maybe there is alternative way to achieve same goal? I assume this has been hidden by MCVE, since simple  classic use of `Foo` does the job (or alow `auto` to deduce return type).

Comment: And why `typedef` not  more modern `using`? Yes I know it fails on every compiler, but this indicates some more significant problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only few places where `this` is allowed to appear and [[expr.prim.this]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.this) lists them all, namely it can appear in declarations of member functions, member function templates and default initializers of non-static data members.

A `typedef` declares a *type alias*, so neither of those above, and therefore `this` is not allowed to appear in the `typedef` declaration. GCC is wrong to accept it.

This rule also makes sense. `this` only really makes sense in a non-static member function definition. Its value and also its type depend on that. For example `this` ought to be `const`-qualified if and only if the non-static member function is `const`-qualified.

However a `typedef` of the form

```
typedef auto getFoo1() -> decltype(*this);
```

has nothing to do with member functions. It simply declares a type alias for an ordinary function type that could be used to declare any function, whether member function or not, and potentially in any class. What type should `this` even have then in this context? `Foo*`, `const Foo*`, etc?

If you need to just refer to the class type itself, use `Foo` directly instead of going through `decltype(*this)`.